# Parsing text from a table of contents using regex

Tags: python, regex

Following is the text I'd like to parse, stored in variable named "toc"

```
                                  Table of Contents
I.   INTRODUCTION          ....................................                                  1
II.  FACTUAL ASPECTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     2
     A.   The Clean Air Act . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  3
     B.   EPA's Gasoline Rule . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    3
          1.     Establishment of Baselines . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      3
          2.     Reformulated Gasoline . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .       4
          3.     Conventional Gasoline (or "Anti-Dumping Rules") . . . . . . . .                 4
     C.   The May 1994 Proposal . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5
III. MAIN ARGUMENTS . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .      5
     A.   General          ....................................                                  5
     B.   The General Agreement on Tariffs and Trade . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .             6
          1.     Article I - General Most-Favoured-Nation Treatment . . . . . . .                6
          2.     Article III - National Treatment on Internal Taxation
                 and Regulation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    7
                 a)      Article III:4 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   7
                 b)      Article III:1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  14
          3.     Article XX - General Exceptions . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .        15
          4.     Article XX(b) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  15
                 a)      "Protection of Human, Animal and Plant Life
                         or Health" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .   15
                 b)      "Necessary" . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    15
          5.     Article XX(d) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  21
          6.     Article XX(g) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22
                 a)      "Related to the conservation of exhaustible natural
                         resources..." . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  22
                 b)      "... made effective in conjunction with restrictions
                         on domestic production or consumption" . . . . . . . . . .             23
          7.     Preamble to Article XX . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .     23
          8.     Article XXIII - Nullification and Impairment . . . . . . . . . . . .           25
```

I want the result like this:

```
['I.INTRODUCTION ...... 1', 'A. The Clean Air Act ....3', 'B. EPA\'s Gasoline Rule ... 3', (AND_SO_ON) ]
```

INPUT:

```
re.search(r"((?<=(\n))\s+(?P<name>[A-Z \.]*?)(\n))", toc_s).group()
```

OUTPUT:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-4aa240f6e378> in <module>()
----> 1 re.search(r"((?<=(\n))\s+(?P<name>[A-Z \.]*?)(\n))", toc_s).group()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

What was my problem?

Comment: The problem was your that `search` returned None, and you called `None.group()` which is invalid in python. The real problem is your regex...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Could  you give me a little hint which point of my regex went wrong?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and additionally, can I ask how did you so easily edited the attached text into a printed form in python? I'd like to learn that skill

Comment: Too long to explain in a comment so wrote an answer. Okay, regarding the second bit, I just loaded the text into a variable on terminal, `print`ed it out, and pasted it again. ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've read your bio and see how you works and realized - "This person is the real !"

Comment: I am indeed a real person, yes. Cheers ;)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I am in Seoul in South Korea and our company looking for some developers. If you know anyone in Seoul, let me know :D

Comment: There are a few Koreans at my university, but they all keep to themselves... :( If anything comes up, I'll get in touch. Good day!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Good DAY!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume this entire TOC content resides in a multiline string `text`. You can use `re.findall` or `re.finditer` with the `re.MULTILINE` switch enabled;

```
for match in re.finditer('(.*?)[\W]+(\d+)(?=\n|$)', text, flags=re.M):
     chapter, page = map(str.strip, match.groups())
     ... # do something with these
```

Or,

```
contents = re.findall('(.*?)[\W]+(\d+)(?=\n|$)', text, flags=re.M)
```

Which returns something along these lines -

```
[('I.   INTRODUCTION', '1'),
 ('II.  FACTUAL ASPECTS', '2'),
 ('     A.   The Clean Air Act', '3'),
 ("     B.   EPA's Gasoline Rule", '3'),
 ('          1.     Establishment of Baselines', '3'),
 ('          2.     Reformulated Gasoline', '4'),
 ...
]
```

A list of 2-tuples. Each tuple has a) the chapter, and b) the corresponding page number. If a line is not matched by the pattern, it is, of course, ignored.

**Details**

The pattern is very specific, and requires some trial-and-error.

```
(         # first capture group - the chapter name
  .*?     # non-greedy match 
)
[\W]+     # match characters that are not alphanumeric
(         # second capture group - the page number
  \d+     # one or more digits
)
(?=       # lookahead for a newline or EOL (multiline)
  \n      # literal newline
  |       # regex OR
  $       # EOL
)
```

Comment: I can't understand how this simple line can returns that tuple consisting of two elements, chapter and page...

contents = re.findall('(.*?)[\W]+(\d+)(?=\n|$)', text, flags=re.M) 

I tried to change re.M into 0, it works same. 

In your regex, there's no delimiter between chapter and page. how did you do this magic?

Comment: In Docstring of re.findall, it says "Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.", however, there's no explanation how can I make tuples..

Comment: @delinco It looks like black magic at first, but it becomes simple once you've understood what the regex is doing and how `re.findall` works. :) The engine finds all strings that match the pattern given, but only returns the substrings specified in the capture groups as a list of tuples.

Comment: If no capture groups are specified, the entire matched string is returned ... (and not just the parts inside the capture groups).

Comment: @now I see.. the re.findall returns each subgroup wrapped in ( ).. and moreover, the each ? question-marks are important which makes the expression non-greedy.. which abridges the part expressed in [\W]. if I didn't use ? at each subgroup, it returns only one tuple

Comment: @delinco Yup... looks like you've gotten the hang of things. :)

Comment: I'd tried flgs = 0 instead of re.M and nothing changed. Docstring says nth about re.M. Could you let me know what the re.M is briefly about?

Comment: @delinco okay, so I'm not 100% sure whether the flag is needed or not.  re.M specifies that I want to perform a match across multiple lines. That probably isn't needed here, so feel free to remove it.